# ComboBox com PHP mudança a de status no banco de dados

Tags: php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Como posso mudar o Campo Status no banco de dados através do ComboBox no PHP? Eu consegui
montar uma mudança de *status* com `onclick`, mas agora preciso mudar com o ComboBox.

```
//PERMISSÃO Nº31 = BLOQUEAR/DESBLOQUEAR OS
        if((array_key_exists(31, $sessao->getMenuPermissao())) && $qtOsIniciada == 0 ){

            if($os->getStatus() == 'BLQ'){
                $bloquearOrdemServico = "<a href='javascript:bloquearOrdemServico( ".$os->getIdOrdemServico().", true )' id='cancelarOrdemServico'
                                            title='Desbloquear OS'>
                                            <img style='width:30px; height:30' src='comum/img/cadeadoAberto.png'>
                                        </a>";
            }
            else{

                $bloquearOrdemServico = "<a href='javascript:bloquearOrdemServico( ".$os->getIdOrdemServico().", false )' id='cancelarOrdemServico'
                                            title='Bloquear OS'>
                                            <img style='width:30px; height:30' src='comum/img/cadeadoFechado.png'>
                                        </a>";
            }
        }
        else{

            $bloquearOrdemServico = '';
        }
```

Comment: Você vai precisar dar mais dicas do que você quer... Você quer mudar o que, para que, qual o motivo, o que você quer fazer?

Comment: bom queria entender como faço pra que  getStatus() == 'BLQ') em vez de ficar BLQ  ele passe a ficar null  por uma comboBox. quando selecionar no campo bloqueado ou desbloqueado respectivamente ele mude o status.

Comment: Sim até ai eu entendi, mas eu estou tentando entender a aplicação prática, me explique um pouco mais sobre sua aplicação para eu poder entender o que ela tem que fazer e te ajudar nisso.

Comment: KhaosDoctor, desculpa brow estava cheio dos problemas e nem tive tempo de entrar para ver as respostas, então se puder me ajudar ainda agradeço. Te explicar melhor eu tenho algumas class.php e o oque eu estou precisando fazer e atualizar vários campos de uma vez através de php e javascript, seria um campo de bloqueio e desbloquio de varias informações ao mesmo, no caso essa informação vem do banco de dados e me é apresentado num site cara você poderia me passar o seu e-mail porque ai eu te mandaria o print da tela e te explicaria com mais detalhes.

Comment: Você consegue recuperar o valor do status selecionado?

Comment: consigo sim! esse codigo ai de cima ele funciona numa boa ele
bloqueia e desbloqueia numa boa, oque eu queria era em vez de bloquear/desbloquear clicando em cima do icone eu queria bloquear/ desbloquear  todas as os de uma unica vez

Comment: Deixa eu entender, você quer um unico combo no topo que bloqueie todos os inputs abaixo? Coloque uma foto por favor.

Comment: isso mesmo!!segue a foto!

Comment: Ah sim, mas essas Ordens estão no banco de dados correto? Você teria que executar uma query no banco para bloqueá-las?

Comment: isso mesmo.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como as ordens de serviço estão em um banco de dados, ao invés de realizar uma query com uma restrição para o ID da ordem, você terá de realizar uma outra query sem restrição, ou então com restrições que apliquem-se ao modo de visualização do usuário. Ex:

Ao invés de usar

```
UPDATE TBL_ORDEM SET STATUS = 'BLOQUEADO' WHERE ID = 123
```

Você terá de usar

```
UPDATE TBL_ORDEM SET STATUS = 'BLOQUEADO'
```

Isto vai variar do seu sistema, ou seja, você terá que (provavelmente) criar uma outra função para enviar o comando para o programa e recarregar a tela da mesma maneira como você faz hoje, porém sem o código da ordem.

Comment: obrigado KhaosDoctor!